# Error while installing json gem 'mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby'

Tags: json, ruby, rubygems

For context, it on a remote server which has a firewall. I'm setting up my environment through a proxy. I have `ruby 1.8.7`. When I try to gem install..

```
sudo gem install --http-proxy <host address>:<port> json
```

I get the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Since I was unsure what the problem is, I googled and found these

- [gem install: Failed to build gem native extension (can't find header files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304438/gem-install-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cant-find-header-files)  - the instructions here seem to be specific to the gem being installed.
- [How to install json gem - Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527092/how-to-install-json-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)   This seems to be slightly different error.

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: check presense of `/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h` file, if it is present, show us error message from `gem_make.out`.

Answer (score 936, accepted):

Modern era update, as [stated by mimoralea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby/26225468#26225468):

> In case that you are using ruby 2.0 or 2.2 (thanks @patrick-davey).
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ruby2.0-dev
> sudo apt-get install ruby2.2-dev
> sudo apt-get install ruby2.3-dev
> ```

or, generic way:

> ```
> sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ruby`ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION[/\d+\.\d+/]'`-dev
> ```

---

The first link you’ve posted is *exactly* your case: there is no ruby development environment installed. Development env is needed to compile ruby extensions, which are mostly written in `C`. Proxy has nothing to do with the problem: everything is downloaded fine, just compilation fails.

I would suggest you to install `ruby-dev` (`ruby-devel` for rpm-based distros) package onto you target machine.

`gcc` package might be needed as well.

Try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Or, for Redhat distro:

```
$ sudo yum install ruby-devel
```

Or, for [open]SuSE:

```
$ sudo zypper install ruby-devel
```

Comment: Thanks! I meant the answer in that question seemed module-specific. I think instead of `ruby-dev` its `ruby-devel`. Here's where I found what I exactly needed - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-centos-6

Comment: After installing ruby-devel (on Fedora 20), I got the error *** extconf.rb failed ***. Once installing gcc as you suggested, everything worked fine.

Comment: You can add `sudo zypper install ruby-devel` for openSUSE

Comment: This does nothing on Ubuntu. The missing package is `ruby2.2-dev` (or whichever version you have installed).

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Back in 2013 there was no `ruby2.2-dev` package in Ubuntu, and I bet this answer helped you to solve the problem.

Comment: Nope, this answer did not help solving anything. The right answer is [the one by mimoralea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26225468/2066215).

Comment: saved my life, in some application's docs there is only ruby-dev (and not ruby-devel). That is confusing to linux beginners.

Comment: On Ubuntu / debian: Run `ruby -v` to determine your ruby version. Run `apt-cache search ruby | grep "[0-9].[0-9]-dev"` to locate the corresponding version-specific dev package.

Comment: or sudo apt-get install ruby2.4-dev (check your ruby version[ruby -v], and install correspondingly)

Comment: @mudasobwa Okay, nice :)

Comment: @mudasobwa Bless your heart stranger.

Comment: How about it for Darwin/macOS?

Comment: No need for you to comment then :P

Comment: i noticed on debian i had to install gcc and make as well

Comment: ```sudo apt-get install ruby`ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION[/\d+\.\d+/]'`-dev 
```

This helped me in WSL! Thank you so much

Answer (score 253):

For **Xcode 11 on macOS 10.14**, this can happen even after installing Xcode and installing command-line tools and accepting the license with

```
sudo xcode-select --install
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

The issue is that Xcode 11 ships the macOS 10.15 SDK which includes headers for ruby2.6, but not for macOS 10.14's ruby2.3. You can verify that this is your problem by running

```
ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'
```

which on macOS 10.14 with Xcode 11 prints the **non-existent** path

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0
```

However, Xcode 11 installs a macOS 10.14 SDK within `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOS10.14.sdk`. It isn't necessary to pollute the system directories by installing the old header files as suggested in other answers. Instead, by selecting that SDK, the appropriate ruby2.3 headers will be found:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'
```

This should now correctly print

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0
```

Likewise, `gem install` should work while that SDK is selected.

To switch back to the current Xcode SDK, use

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Comment: If you need (or want) to switch the chosen Xcode SDK for a single command or script, you can make use of the `DEVELOPER_DIR` environment variable as documented in `xcode-select(1)`. For example: `DEVELOPER_DIR=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/ bundle install`

Comment: The solution worked but switching it this way breaks some functionality. `xcodebuild` for example stops working.

Answer (score 81):

In case that you are using ruby 2.0 or 2.2 (thanks @patrick-davey) or 2.3 (thanks @juanitofatas).

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby2.2-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby2.3-dev
```

And you get the pattern here...

Comment: Or, if you're using 2.2 ... `sudo apt-get install ruby2.2-dev`

Comment: @patrick-davey 
`E: Unable to locate package ruby2.2-dev`
`E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ruby2.2-dev'`

Comment: @dson probably you use an old Ubuntu version. Try upgrading.

Comment: I got the same error as well, and I'm using a fully updated version of Linux Mint. I don't think the OS verison is the issue.

Comment: If you're using an old version of Ubuntu such as Trusty (14.04), add the brightbox PPA for Ruby: `sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y ruby2.2-dev`

Answer (score 24):

I also encountered this problem because I [install Ruby on Ubuntu via brightbox](https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2016/01/06/ruby-2-3-ubuntu-packages/), and I thought ruby-dev is the trunk of ruby. So I did not install. Install ruby2.3-dev fixes it:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.3-dev
```

Answer (score 21):

For those who are getting this on Mac OS X you may need to run the following command to install the XCode command-line tools, even if you already have XCode installed:

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Also you must agree the terms and conditions of XCode by running the following command:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. I had no Ruby Development Headers. Once I installed xCode the original command I tried running worked. Thanks!

Comment: On OSX with Mojave I had to run that as: `su - $USER -c 'xcode-select --install'`

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem using cygwin to run the following command:

```
$ gem install rerun
```

I solved it by installing the following cygwin packages:

- ruby-devel
- libffi-devel
- gcc-core
- gcc-g++
- make
- automake1.15

Comment: This segfaults for me: `/cygdrive/z/.gem/ruby/extensions/x86-cygwin/json-1.8.3/json/ext/parser.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0001b8`

Comment: Resolved by doing `rm -rf ~/.gem/` and reissuing the command.

Comment: `ruby-dev` on raspberry pi

Answer (score 13):

Most voted solution didn't work on my machine (linux mint 18.04).
After a careful look, i found that g++ was missing.
Solved with

> sudo apt-get install g++

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. I also had to do a sudo apt-get install make prior to the g++ install to work.

Comment: Can confirm installing `make` and `g++` fixed my issue on Ubuntu 18.04, too!

Answer (score 8):

in case you use SUSE

```
sudo yast2 -i ruby-devel
```

Comment: I prefer `sudo zypper in ruby-devel`.

Answer (score 8):

## Xcode 11 / macOS Catalina

On Xcode 11 / macOS Catalina, the header files are no longer in the old location and the old `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` file is no longer available.

Instead, the headers are now installed to the `/usr/include` directory of the current SDK path:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

Most of this directory can be found by using the output of `xcrun --show-sdk-path`. And if you add this path to the `CPATH` environment variable, then build scripts (including those called via `bundle`) will generally be able to find it.

I resolved this by setting my `CPATH` in my `.zshrc` file:

```
export CPATH="$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include"
```

After opening a new shell (or running `source .zshrc`), I no longer receive the error message *mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h* and the rubygems install properly.

> ### Note on Building to Non-macOS Platforms
>
> If you are building to non-macOS platforms, such as iOS/tvOS/watchOS, this change will attempt to include the macOS SDK in those platforms, causing build errors. To resolve, either don't set `CPATH` environment variable on login, or temporarily set it to blank when running `xcodebuild` like so:
>
> ```
> CPATH="" xcodebuild --some-args
> ```

Comment: Do you have any documentation on CPATH? Setting it is not solving the issue for me. When I checked it’s value in its first place it appeared undefined.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html - you may need to find a different environment variable depending on the language/compiler you’re using. It’s normal that it would be unset by default

Comment: And, in case you haven't seen it elsewhere, there can't be spaces in the Xcode path/name

Comment: From all the answers here, this the only solution that worked for me. I am on `Mojave 10.14.6` and `XCode 11.3.1`.
Thank you so much, took me 1 day to resolve this :/

Answer (score 5):

In Fedora 21 and up, you simply open a terminal and install the Ruby Development files as root.

```
dnf install ruby-devel
```

Answer (score 5):

On Mac 10.14, the header files don't seem to be installed in the correct place. Rather than changing paths like the other fixes, I was able to just run this:

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Follow the instructions and it resolved this problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to install gcc after install ruby-devel

Answer (score 1):

Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations

change Command Line Tools to Xcode 11.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the entire ruby and not just the minimum package. The correct command to use is:

```
sudo apt install ruby-full
```

The following command will also not install a complete ruby:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18, after checking log file mentioned while install

Results logged to /var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nio4r-2.5.2/gem_make.out

with

```
less /var/canvas/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nio4r-2.5.2/gem_make.out
```

I noticed that `make` is not found. So installed make by

```
sudo apt-get install make
```

everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue on **Xcode 12** with macOS **10.15** and cocoapods. Just make sure that the xcode-select command points to the SDK you want to build against. It should build without issues afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

**BEFORE** you follow the tip from Joki's answer (below) and **IF** :

- you have MacOS 10.14.6
- at /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/ you have folders
  MacOSX.sdk(symbolic), MacOSX10.14.sdk, MacOSX10.15.sdk
- Move MacOSX10.15.sdk to anywhere (admin privileges needs)
- Delete symbolic link (admin privileges needs)
- At /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/ create another symbolic link now to MacOSX10.14.sdk folder using (admin privileges needs)

  sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk MacOSX.sdk
- **Now you can follow Joki's answer**

**WARNING!**
If you move MacOSX10.15.sdk folder to /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/ again, the command

```
ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'
```

will show  MacOSX10.15.sdk folder like default again, nowadays I dunno how to fix it! My suggestion, compress the folder and put the original folder until fix will be available.

Answer (score 0):

**macOS RubyMine Gem installation failure**

My problem with this error message was when trying to install a Gem via RubyMine. It didn't like that I had changed the global Ruby version with `rbenv`, so I fixed it by changing back to the system default Ruby version with:

`rbenv global system`

and restarted RubyMine.

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ruby
```

try it for ubuntu 16.04