# Can't install JSON gem on RedHat 7

Tags: json, rubygems, redhat

On RedHat 7 (ec2 image provided by AWS), I'm unable to install the json gem:

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h

I've tried all manner of packages libyaml-devel etc and nothing seems to work.

I've already run through: 
[Error while installing json gem 'mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo rpm -Uvh ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/centos/7.0.1406/os/x86_64/Packages/ruby-devel-2.0.0.353-20.el7.x86_64.rpm`

This seemed to fix it since sudo yum ruby-devel doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

rhel tucks things like this away in the 'optional' repo... you can enable this for aws/ec2 supplied images in:

/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat-rhui.repo

```
[rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 Optional (RPMs)
mirrorlist=https://rhui2-cds01.REGION.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/mirror/content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/$relea$
**enabled=1**
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
sslverify=1
sslclientkey=/etc/pki/rhui/content-rhel7.key
sslclientcert=/etc/pki/rhui/product/content-rhel7.crt
sslcacert=/etc/pki/rhui/cdn.redhat.com-chain.crt
```

Or just do a one-time install:

yum install ruby-devel --enablerepo=rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional

Answer (score 0):

And if you are using subscription-manager:
`subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms`

Then: `sudo yum install -y ruby-devel`