# Ruby on rails - Error during bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been googling this error below, but I can't solve this error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb 
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/dyego/.bundler/tmp/9200/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/dyego/.bundler/tmp/9200/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/sqlite3-1.3.9/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:296:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:168:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `block in resolve'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `resolve'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

So I googled this error:

> mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

and I got some similar questions like this one:
[Error while installing json gem 'mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby)

But I already installed ruby-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ruby-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 72 not upgraded.
```

I'm really struggling to solve this problem (even though it seems to be a simple one).

Comment: did you try installing `sudo apt-get install ruby2.1-dev` ?

Comment: what happens when you run `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'`?

Comment: Use `rvm`. Do not put Ruby to your environment, since you'll probably work with different version of Rubies across your projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I just did what @Alireza said and it's working now thanks for the help and I'll keep in mind what you guys said!

Comment: @user309838 great, I'll post it as an answer then, so you can accept  it as the solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try to install the `ruby-dev` library for your Ruby version which is **2.1**

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby2.1-dev
```

Comment: If you're lazy and it's not a production system, just installing `ruby-dev` also does the trick. And yes, I realize it's amusing that I'm putting more effort into this comment than it would've taken for me to type the extra 3 characters necessary for version specificity. I blame society.

Comment: By now it should be `ruby-2.3-dev`. You can figure out the package name by running ` apt-cache search "ruby.*-dev"` if you're on a Debian-based distribution (e.g. Ubuntu, Mint).

Answer (score 3):

Had similar error on fedora when trying to install compass for SASS development

```
gem install compass
```

failed with

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h

Ran this

```
yum -y install gcc ruby-devel rubygems
```

and then was able to run the install again successfully.

Comment: I get `No package ruby-devel available.` when executing `yum -y install ruby-devel`.

Is there a newer package to install?

Comment: This is the answer that helped me when I was trying to install compass. However, rubygems wasn't necessary. I just used sudo yum install ruby-devel gcc -y