# Sudo gem install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sudo

ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0 -r ./siteconf20190304-9093-ehjkih.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts  -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in`block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in`try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:138:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:162:in`block in add_cflags'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:629:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:161:in`add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:416:in `'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-16/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.10.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-16/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.10.1/gem_make.out

Comment: I checked the gem, it's installed latest version

Comment: *Duplicate See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388127/error-installing-rails-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension.

Answer (score 0):

first, run this command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

then, run this command

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

this will install dependencies. gem native extension successfully build.

Comment: I'm using mac , so please help me out of this

Comment: What is the solution for MAC user? because apt-get is not found command