# Error installing json using gem. Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to install rails and I am receiving the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby2.2 -r ./siteconf20150420-9274-14pi84x.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/json-1.8.2/gem_make.out
```

I have seen similar questions asked and answered but non seem to solve my problem

Comment: It can't find ruby sources. Have you installed `ruby-dev`? Try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue on my Ubuntu server. This [article](https://github.com/flori/json/issues/253) helped me out.

All I had to do is to install libgmp3-dev.

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```