# Use of external .js & css files fails

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design a web site with bootstrap and I downloaded code for registration page

There are 3 files:

HTML,
CSS
and .js

**registration.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Code </title>
    <link href="css/my.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/b.js"></script>
  </head>  
<body>  
<div class="form">

      <ul class="tab-group">
        <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="signup">   
          <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

          <form action="/" method="post">

          <div class="top-row">
            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                First Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
              <label>
                Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get Started</button>

          </form>

        </div>

        <div id="login">   
          <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

          <form action="/" method="post">

            <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>

          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>
              Password<span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>

          <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

          <button class="button button-block"/>Log In</button>

          </form>

        </div>

      </div><!-- tab-content -->

</div> <!-- /form -->
</body>
```

**my.css**

```
@import "compass/css3";

$body-bg: #c1bdba;
$form-bg: #13232f;
$white: #ffffff;

$main: #1ab188;
$main-light: lighten($main,5%);
$main-dark: darken($main,5%);

$gray-light: #a0b3b0;
$gray: #ddd;

$thin: 300;
$normal: 400;
$bold: 600;
$br: 4px;

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}

body {
  background:$body-bg;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:$main;
  transition:.5s ease;
  &:hover {
    color:$main-dark;
  }
}

.form {
  background:rgba($form-bg,.9);
  padding: 40px;
  max-width:600px;
  margin:40px auto;
  border-radius:$br;
  box-shadow:0 4px 10px 4px rgba($form-bg,.3);
}

.tab-group {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0 0 40px 0;
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  li a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:15px;
    background:rgba($gray-light,.25);
    color:$gray-light;
    font-size:20px;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:.5s ease;
    &:hover {
      background:$main-dark;
      color:$white;
    }
  }
  .active a {
    background:$main;
    color:$white;
  }
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display:none;
}


h1 {
  text-align:center;
  color:$white;
  font-weight:$thin;
  margin:0 0 40px;
}

label {
  position:absolute;
  transform:translateY(6px);
  left:13px;
  color:rgba($white,.5);
  transition:all 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size:22px;
  .req {
    margin:2px;
    color:$main;
  }
}

label.active {
  transform:translateY(50px);
  left:2px;
  font-size:14px;
  .req {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

label.highlight {
    color:$white;
}

input, textarea {
  font-size:22px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background:none;
  background-image:none;
  border:1px solid $gray-light;
  color:$white;
  border-radius:0;
  transition:border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
  &:focus {
        outline:0;
        border-color:$main;
  }
}

textarea {
  border:2px solid $gray-light;
  resize: vertical;
}

.field-wrap {
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:40px;
}

.top-row {
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  > div {
    float:left;
    width:48%;
    margin-right:4%;
    &:last-child { 
      margin:0;
    }
  }
}

.button {
  border:0;
  outline:none;
  border-radius:0;
  padding:15px 0;
  font-size:2rem;
  font-weight:$bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:.1em;
  background:$main;
  color:$white;
  transition:all.5s ease;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  &:hover, &:focus {
    background:$main-dark;
  }
}

.button-block {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}

.forgot {
  margin-top:-20px;
  text-align:right;
}
```

**b.js**

```
$('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {

  var $this = $(this),
      label = $this.prev('label');

      if (e.type === 'keyup') {
            if ($this.val() === '') {
          label.removeClass('active highlight');
        } else {
          label.addClass('active highlight');
        }
    } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
        if( $this.val() === '' ) {
            label.removeClass('active highlight'); 
            } else {
            label.removeClass('highlight');   
            }   
    } else if (e.type === 'focus') {

      if( $this.val() === '' ) {
            label.removeClass('highlight'); 
            } 
      else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
            label.addClass('highlight');
            }
    }

});

$('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

  target = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();

  $(target).fadeIn(600);

});
```

I downloaded it and put the html file in the website folder
& the css and js files in the css and js folders respectively.

Then I tried to call these external files:

```
<link href="css/my.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/b.js"></script>
```

but failed.

I think the css rule is the reason or the the code for using external ".js" files & css files

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have in `my.css` is not CSS - it's SCSS, which needs to be compiled into CSS. You can read more about SASS/SCSS here:

http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: so what should i do ? setup it first !?

Comment: in installed it ! then !??

Comment: sass my.scss my.css from your shell. You must be in the folder that contains my.scss or include the path to it when running the above command.

Comment: You also need to install compass.

Comment: i tried but ERROR:  Error installing compass:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/ffi-1.9.10/gem_make.out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby