# Missing gem Faraday

Tags: ruby, rubygems, faraday

I'm new to Ruby and I'm just trying to run a script. Firstly, when I try to bundle install it says:

```
    Daniels-Air:Documents Daniel$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Rubygems 2.0.3 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
Installing ffi 1.9.10 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/_r/8pxmrph95fj0km8h7sfkw9f40000gn/T/bundler20151216-21689-8jiqebffi-1.9.10/gems/ffi-1.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/_r/8pxmrph95fj0km8h7sfkw9f40000gn/T/bundler20151216-21689-8jiqebffi-1.9.10/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/_r/8pxmrph95fj0km8h7sfkw9f40000gn/T/bundler20151216-21689-5mz4k9json-1.8.3/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/_r/8pxmrph95fj0km8h7sfkw9f40000gn/T/bundler20151216-21689-5mz4k9json-1.8.3/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using rubyzip 1.1.7
Using websocket 1.2.2
Using bundler 1.11.1
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I then try to execute the file anyway I come across the problem:

```
    Could not find gem 'faraday' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Where do I get this 'faraday' gem from? Should it have come with the code I am trying to run, or should I update something? Sorry if I got some terminology wrong, I'm very new to Ruby.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while installing json gem 'mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realised all I needed to do was install the gem. Its made clear from the RubyGems.org library. Just typed:

```
sudo gem install faraday
```

to the terminal