# mysql2 gem not loaded installing redmine-agile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm trying to install the [Redmine Agile plugin](https://www.redmineup.com/pages/help/agile/installing-redmine-agile-plugin-on-linux), and I can't get through step 4:

```
/var/www/html/redmine$ sudo bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_agile RAILS_ENV=production
(in /usr/share/redmine)
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/lib/tasks/redmine.rake:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/lib/tasks/redmine.rake:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:plugins:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I previously had been unable to `sudo gem install mysql2`, but got around that by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39745512/1102726).

I did try adding `gem "mysql2"`, but that did not resolve the issue.

```
/var/www/html/redmine$ cat plugins/redmine_agile/Gemfile
gem "redmine_crm"
gem "mysql2"
```

I'm not sure what to make of `and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord`. I'm not sure how to check what that is. I know I can set versions of a gem in the Gemfile, but I don't know what it would be set to.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, MySQL 5.7.22. I'm serving Redmine using something [similar to this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/452230/114689).

***UPDATE***

When I tried to `rake` as `www-data`, the error I got changed to

```
www-data@host:/usr/share/redmine/public/plugins/redmine_agile$ bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_agile RAILS_ENV=production
`/home/ubuntu` is not writable.
Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler/home/ubuntu' as your home directory temporarily.
Could not find gem 'redmine_crm' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

(Trying to `rake` from `/var/www/html/redmine` kept getting me the mysql2 error.)

I then tried to install `redmine_crm`. I couldn't do this as `www-data`, so I did it as root:

```
/var/www/html/redmine/plugins/redmine_agile$ sudo gem install redmine_crm
```

I then tried `bundle install` but got

```
There was an error while trying to write to
`/usr/share/redmine/public/plugins/redmine_agile/Gemfile.lock`. It is likely that you need to grant
write permissions for that path.
```

So I ran that as root.

```
/var/www/html/redmine/plugins/redmine_agile$ sudo bundle install
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as
root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 12.3.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 4.2.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using nokogiri 1.6.7.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
Using crass 1.0.4
Using loofah 2.2.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
Using actionview 4.2.6
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.6
Using globalid 0.4.1
Using activejob 4.2.6
Using mini_mime 1.0.0
Using mail 2.7.0
Using actionmailer 4.2.6
Using activemodel 4.2.6
Using arel 6.0.3
Using activerecord 4.2.6
Using bundler 1.16.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using liquid 2.6.3
Using mysql2 0.5.2
Using thor 0.20.0
Using railties 4.2.6
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 4.2.6
Using redmine_crm 0.0.42
Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 37 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Trying `rake` then got me a different error.

```
ubuntu@host:/var/www/html/redmine/plugins/redmine_agile$ sudo bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_agile RAILS_ENV=production
(in /usr/share/redmine)
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::XmlParamsParser
/usr/share/redmine/config/application.rb:55:in `<class:Application>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/application.rb:8:in `<module:RedmineApp>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/usr/share/redmine/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Trying that from the `redmine` per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48441490/1102726) directory failed with the mysql2 gem error.

```
ubuntu@host:/var/www/html/redmine/plugins/redmine_agile$ cd ../..
ubuntu@host:/var/www/html/redmine$ sudo bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_agile RAILS_ENV=production
(in /usr/share/redmine)
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/lib/tasks/redmine.rake:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
/usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/redmine/lib/tasks/redmine.rake:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => redmine:plugins:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnecessary use of `sudo` to run a command as `root` is a common cause of issues to find resolve some gems.

In almost all cases, you should thus not not use `sudo` to run your rake tasks. Instead, use the user which normally usually runs the app server, e.g. `www-data`.

```
# first change to the user that usually runs your app
sudo -u www-data /bin/bash -i
/var/www/html/redmine

# Now run your rake task (without prefixing it with sudo)
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_agile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and apologies for taking a while to get back to you. I'm about to update my question.

Answer (score 1):

This error is clearly saying that you have not installed `Gem 'mysql2'` have you ran command `bundle install`? can you try following

On your project root folder please run following command

```
gem list mysql2
```

It should show you local gems and also list mysql2 as installed

In case it is not installed, that means you either you can't install mysql2 or you have not run `bundle install` command. Maybe you can try the following

Add the following line in your `Gemfile`

```
gem "mysql2", "0.3.14"
```

now run following command

```
bundle install
```

Now check if mysql2 is really installed

```
gem list mysql2
```

If yes then all good, hope it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. When I run `gem list mysql2`, I get `mysql2 (0.5.2, 0.4.3)`. Thoughts?

Comment: Okay, I ended up running `sudo gem install redmine_crm` and then `sudo bundle install` and got to a new error.

Comment: That means you previous error gone, kindly accept response and put the new question with the detail of new error message.

Comment: Because the other answer's suggestion was the one that most directly led me to make progress, I've accepted that as the answer.