# Ubuntu, Ruby, Ruby on Rails Installation Problems (Cant visit localhost:3000)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

This is my first time learning to code, first time on Linux and first time on stackeroverflow so I dont know if its glaringly obvious where I have gone wrong.

I have followed this guide https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04 and everything was working as the guide said until I got to this section:

> run  bundle install --local
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/generators/app_base.rb:328:in `bundle_command'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/generators/app_base.rb:344:in`run_bundle'
>       from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/command.rb:27:in`run'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`block in invoke_all'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in`map'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/group.rb:232:in`dispatch'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in`'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from /usr/bin/rails:9:in`'
>   tom@Laptop:~$ cd myapp
>   tom@Laptop:~/myapp$ rake db:create
>   rake aborted!
>   LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
>   /home/tom/myapp/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
>   /home/tom/myapp/config/application.rb:1:in`'
>   /home/tom/myapp/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
>   tom@Laptop:~/myapp$ rails server
>   /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from /home/tom/myapp/config/boot.rb:3:in`'
>       from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
>       from bin/rails:3:in`'

Sorry I don't know how to format this correctly.
When I visit localhost:3000 I just get Network error.

Has anyone got any idea how to solve this? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem install bundler`. After that use `bundle install` in terminal.

Comment: I used sudo gem install then the bundle install gives me this error:

'code'Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/tmp/bundler20161105-11803-1jw9vv3debug_inspector-0.0.2/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/ext/debug_inspector
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20161105-11803-14wcuhn.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

An error occurred while installing debug_inspector (0.0.2), and Bundler
cannot continue.

Comment: and it gave me this: Make sure that `gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2'` succeeds before
bundling. 

So i did sudo gem install debug_inspector -v '0.0.2' and tried it again and it still gave the same error

Comment: Put `gem install debug_inspector` in gemfile. Delete `gemfile.lock` and then try `bundle install` in terminal again.

Comment: where would gemfile.lock be located?

Comment: In your App directory. Look at the last files in your app.

Comment: @TomArmstrong see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby, you need to install a ruby-dev package. In this case if you googled `can't find header files for ruby ` you would have found a solution.