# Sass installation error

Tags: ruby, sass, frontend

I use Linux Mint and I want to install sass. I have installed ruby by "sudo apt install ruby" , version 2.3 and then , when I wan to install sass by "sudo gem install sass --no-user-install" , I have the following error:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171114-19329-157auxp.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2):

Install this package:

```
sudo apt install ruby-dev
```

The [ruby-dev package](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/ruby-dev) contains the missing headers. You can see that the installer is looking for the headers:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
```

Installing this package will install those headers. This is a common issue that comes up for new Ruby users when installing gems with native extensions. You may find that you have to install several packages to get the installation to complete. If you see similar errors when installing this gem or other gems, try searching for "gemname native extension prerequisites", like "[sass gem native extension prerequisites](https://www.google.com/search?q=sass+gem+native+extension+prerequisites)", to learn which packages should be installed before installing the gem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install ruby-full rubygems autogen autoconf libtool make
sudo gem install sass
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04, `ruby-dev` itself didn't help, installing `g++` and `make`, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50223278/570763) solved my issue.