# An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to run the `bundle install` command and I got the following errors. After reading some stackoverflow posts, I also ran **`bundle update`**.

I am still getting the issue of `json ~ 1.8.6` gem (I guess).

> An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before
>   bundling.
>   Here the issue is not getting installation done properly.

[image]

[image: I tried installing gem separately.But still the problem exists.]

Comment: try installing gem install json -v '1.8.6' manually in command line first

Comment: @TomLord I did the generic way and it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: @HaiderAli Thanks,
I've written the answer for it with yours and TomLord 's inputs. Hope this would be effective for others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while installing json gem 'mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by doing the following

**1.** Installing the ruby development environment by running the following command(for Linux machines).

```sh
sudo apt-get install ruby
ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION[/\d+\.\d+/]' -dev
```

Read this post for [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby).

**2.** Now install the `json -v '1.8.6'` gem by running the following command.

```sh
sudo gem install json -v '1.8.6'
```

This should solve the issue. Now try running `bundle update` and `bundle install` and it should work fine.

Thanks [@TomLord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954610/tom-lord) and [@Haider Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2671192/haider-ali) for your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of json gem have some incompatibilities with newer ruby. Try to update json gem `bundle update json`