# Can I use PRY with alpine-linux?

Tags: ruby, irb, alpine-linux, pry

I got ruby and ruby-irb installed

For irb, `apk add irb-pry` was the answer

then

```
irb
irb(main):00:0>
```

works

Now I would like to get PRY working.

I got the gem installed but then I got:

```
03:36:00  848c4ae29411 / 
# gem install pry
Successfully installed pry-0.12.0
Parsing documentation for pry-0.12.0
Installing ri documentation for pry-0.12.0
Done installing documentation for pry after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
03:36:11  848c4ae29411 / 
# pry
Traceback (most recent call last):
        16: from /usr/bin/pry:23:in `<main>'
        15: from /usr/bin/pry:23:in `load'
        14: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.12.0/bin/pry:4:in `<top (required)>'
        13: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        12: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        11: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.12.0/lib/pry.rb:110:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         9: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         8: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.12.0/lib/pry/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
         7: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.12.0/lib/pry/commands.rb:4:in `each'
         6: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.12.0/lib/pry/commands.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
         5: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         4: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         3: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.12.0/lib/pry/commands/gem_stats.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
         2: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.12.0/lib/pry/commands/gem_stats.rb:2:in `<class:GemStat>'
         1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- json (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to,

`gem install pry`

then

`pry`

to get an interactive Pry session.

Comment: ^Thanks.  That also gives me the json error, this time when installing the ri documentation

Comment: how about trying `gem install json; gem update json` and then `gem install pry`

Comment: Thanks.  This time I got ```
# gem install json
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181111-95-rnpd7u.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0...
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/g...
```
i found that .../include didn't exist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby

Comment: Thanks! IO installed ruby-dev and it installed ok butr now I get

Comment: ```# gem install json
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181111-168-18pqcph.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean
sh: make: not found

current directory: /usr/lib/ruby...
make "DESTDIR="
sh: make: not found

make failed, exit code 127
```

Comment: Stop adding this info in comments. Put it into your question as a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Alpine is an intentionally bare-bones Linux distribution, which means that you have to install libraries and programs yourself before allowing `gem` to install packages.

This worked for me to get `pry` running from the Alpine Docker image:

```
apk update
apk add ruby-dev make gcc libc-dev

gem install json pry --no-document
```