# Ruby Gem FFI won't build for Jekyll Website, mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll, bundler, ffi

I'm just trying to get my Jekyll site to deploy locally, but ffi has started throwing errors that prevent it doing so.

I've tried building multiple versions of the gem, and I've tried various fixes, but I have been unable to get any of them to resolve the issue. I've ensured command line tools are installed as well.

Below I've included all the commands and results, including attempted fixes. What's the recommended next step?

```
> bundle install
Ignoring ffi-1.9.24 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.24
Ignoring ffi-1.9.23 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.23
Ignoring http_parser.rb-0.6.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine http_parser.rb --version 0.6.0
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using public_suffix 2.0.5
Using addressable 2.5.0
Using bundler 1.16.2
Using colorator 1.1.0
Fetching ffi 1.9.17


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.
  You can cancel this installation and run:

      bundle install --path vendor/bundle

  to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
  and install the bundled gems to RubyGems using sudo.

  Password:


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.
  You can cancel this installation and run:

      bundle install --path vendor/bundle

  to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
  and install the bundled gems to RubyGems using sudo.

  Password:
Installing ffi 1.9.17 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/private/var/folders/py/84q2xtqd7_32k8zh940lp_180000gn/T/bundler20181122-19575-17juyrkffi-1.9.17/gems/ffi-1.9.17/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r
./siteconf20181122-19575-nhgtbt.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/var/folders/py/84q2xtqd7_32k8zh940lp_180000gn/T/bundler20181122-19575-17juyrkffi-1.9.17/gems/ffi-1.9.17
for inspection.
Results logged to
/var/folders/py/84q2xtqd7_32k8zh940lp_180000gn/T/bundler20181122-19575-17juyrkffi-1.9.17/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.17/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.17), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.17' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  jekyll-feed was resolved to 0.9.1, which depends on
    jekyll was resolved to 3.3.1, which depends on
      jekyll-watch was resolved to 1.5.0, which depends on
        listen was resolved to 3.0.8, which depends on
          rb-inotify was resolved to 0.9.8, which depends on
            ffi
```

---

```
> sudo gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.24
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Ext::BuildError)
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.24/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181122-19602-ujwrh1.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.24 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.24/gem_make.out
```

---

```
> sudo gem install ffi -v '1.9.17' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.17/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181122-19646-7mh82e.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.17 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.17/gem_make.out
```

---

```
> brew install libffi

Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!

Warning: libffi 3.2.1 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link libffi` to link this version.
MacBook-Pro% brew link libffi
Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: libffi
For compilers to find libffi you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"

For pkg-config to find libffi you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"

> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
> export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
> brew link libffi
Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: libffi
For compilers to find libffi you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"

For pkg-config to find libffi you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
```

---

```
> sudo gem install ffi
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181122-27707-hnmli3.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:524:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1091:in `block in have_header'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1090:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.25/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.25/gem_make.out
```

---

Contents of mkmf.log:

```
"pkg-config --exists libffi"
package configuration for libffi is not found
"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/universal-darwin18 -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib -L.     -lruby.2.3.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:36:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/defines.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:66:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/wait.h:110:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:72:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:2:10: error: #include nested too deeply
#include <stddef.h>
         ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:59:11: error: #include nested too deeply
# include <stdint.h>
          ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:72:11: error: #include nested too deeply
# include <sys/types.h>
          ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:76:10: error: #include nested too deeply
#include <limits.h>
         ^
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:82:11: error: #include nested too deeply
# include <inttypes.h>
          ^
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:36:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/defines.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:66:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/wait.h:110:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:197:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_user_time;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:198:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_system_time;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:199:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_pkg_idle_wkups;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:200:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_interrupt_wkups;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:201:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_pageins;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:202:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_wired_size;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:203:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_resident_size;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:204:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_phys_footprint;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:205:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_proc_start_abstime;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:206:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_proc_exit_abstime;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:211:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_user_time;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:212:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_system_time;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:213:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_pkg_idle_wkups;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/resource.h:214:2: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
        uint64_t ri_interrupt_wkups;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.3.8`; install bundler with `gem install bundler`; re-run `bundle install` (which should now be using RVM's installed version of Ruby, not the system version of Ruby). If it still doesn't work, then post the errors. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: This eventually fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: don't use system Ruby or help it find the corresponding headers in the correct SDK ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/a/58231417/4618482