# Error: Failed to build gem native extension building listen gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have been trying to run `gem install listen` and I saw this error below.

> ERROR:  Error installing listen:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.11.3/ext/ffi_c
>   /usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20200106-9209-e0kdmx.rb extconf.rb
>   mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

"can't find header files for ruby" explains the issue best. Make sure to install Ruby developer libraries.
Depending on your OS and package manager, try

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

or

```
sudo yum install ruby-dev
```

or

```
sudo apk add ruby-dev
```

or

```
xcode-select --install
```

Also, please check out [Error while installing json gem 'mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby) and similar proposed solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot..I had issues with cocoa pods install.."xcode-select --install" this fixed my problem