# Centos 7: Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4' --source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems, capistrano

Trying to deploy app on production through Capistrano.

postgres version is 9.2.24

```
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/pg-0.18.4/mkmf.log
```

Tried following solutions but nothing worked

1. Tried manual installation on production server

   ```
   sudo gem install pg -v 0.18.4
   ```
2. [Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header when trying to install pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040583/cant-find-the-libpq-fe-h-header-when-trying-to-install-pg-gem)
3. [Error while installing json gem 'mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby)

Comment: You have `postgresql-devel` and `postgresql-libs`?

Comment: yum info returns Error: No matching Packages to list

Comment: Try add the needed RPM

Comment: @matanco it says both packages are already installed

Comment: packge is added with name postgresql92-libs

Comment: Do not install gems with sudo!