# What is the last Flutter version compatible with Xcode 11.3.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm trying to build my Flutter app on Mac os Catalina. And would like to support old phone like Ipad 2. I read on a post the maximun version of Xcode should be 11.3.1, so i install that then install the newest version of Flutter.

But when if run

```
flutter build ios
```

i got `Found "Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C505". Xcode 12.0.1 or greater is required to develop for iOS.`
So i'm trying to downgrade Flutter to the lastest version compatible with Xcode 11.3.1.

Found [list of old releases](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos) but it's not easy get infos on compatibility with Xcode.

I use command line only (because VMware too slow).

Comment: did you found it ?

Comment: my last try on MacOS Catalina was Xcode 11.3.1 and Flutter 1.22.6 and i think it worked, but i give up for other reasons.

Comment: it's working with Flutter 2.0.6 but I don't know if it can work in newer versions of Flutter with Xcode 11.3.1

Answer (score 0):

At my MBP mid 2012 and iMac late 2012 with Mojave 10.14.6 and Xcode 11.3.1, I have flutter 2.0.6.

After install, if you run flutter -v doctor, you will receive a message:
"! Xcode 11.3.1 out of date (12.0.1 is recommended).
Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store."

but you can run flutter code without troubles.

If I try run flutter 2.2.X, ‘flutter -v doctor’ returns a message that Xcode 12 is need.

**Disclaimer for macOS 10.14.6 users:**

I remember when I installed flutter, at some point I needed install gems dependencies, but I had trouble because I was using Mojave 10.14.6, Xcode and flutter.

If you have troubles with gems installation, please go to [Error while installing json gem 'mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby)

and check my answer for Mojave 10.14.6 (answered Nov 18 '20 at 14:08)