# Can't install a gem on CentOS 8

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Use root user installed rubygems.

```
# yum install rubygems -y
```

When check ruby's version, got

```
# ruby -v
ruby 2.5.9p229 (2021-04-05 revision 67939) [x86_64-linux]
```

Gem's version:

```
# gem -v
2.7.6.3
```

When install a gem, got

```
# gem install fluent-plugin-kinesis
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fluent-plugin-kinesis:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/share/gems/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/ext/msgpack
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20210825-20925-17fyw57.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/msgpack-1.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/msgpack-1.4.2/gem_make.out
```

Should I install a high version ruby? It's the default one on the system.

---

## update

I installed `ruby-devel`

```
# yum install ruby-devel.x86_64
```

Run install `fluent-plugin-kinesis` gem again

```
# gem install fluent-plugin-kinesis
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fluent-plugin-kinesis:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/share/gems/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/ext/msgpack
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20210826-11878-18i9eps.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/st.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:590:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:1098:in `block in have_header'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:948:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:947:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:1097:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:3:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/msgpack-1.4.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/msgpack-1.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/msgpack-1.4.2/gem_make.out
```

For other gems works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.fluentd.org/installation/install-by-gem) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20561594/11509906).

> Install Ruby **>= 2.4** on your local environment. In addition, **install ruby-dev** package via Package Manager to build native extension gems.

I believe in CentOS `ruby-dev` equivalent is `ruby-devel`. You can confirm it by running `yum search ruby-dev`

You'll find 2 packages, one `i686` and another `x86_64`. You can find which one you need by running `lscpu | grep Arch`.

Then simply download the package, and rerun `gem install`

Comment: I added `update` to the question. I did by your guide but still can't install the gem. In [Before Installation](https://docs.fluentd.org/installation/before-install) I didn't find some settings for gem. But I installed the plugin by `td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-kinesis`.

Comment: My bad I was expecting this to work ! Maybe we can have a look at `mkmf.log` and try to figure out if there's a missing header / library if you want to understand why it failed.

Comment: I checked the mkmf.log file, the content is the same as the stdout log. But I can install the special gem in another way. Thank you all the same.