# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension unicode.c:1058:20: [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rubymine, rbenv

Some details about my environment:

- Ruby version: ruby 3.2.0
- RubyGems version: 3.5.6
- rbenv version: 1.2.0
- MacOS: Sonoma 14.1.2 / M2

I'm trying to run **bundle install** to install the gems for my project but I'm getting the following error:

```
Installing unicode 0.4.4.4 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.4/ext/unicode
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/bin/ruby -I /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0 extconf.rb --with-cflags\=-Wno-error\=implicit-function-declaration
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.4/ext/unicode
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20240308-48017-ak1bt1 sitelibdir\=./.gem.20240308-48017-ak1bt1 clean

current directory: /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.4/ext/unicode
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20240308-48017-ak1bt1 sitelibdir\=./.gem.20240308-48017-ak1bt1
compiling unicode.c
unicode.c:37:7: warning: 'RB_OBJ_TAINTED' is deprecated: taintedness turned out to be a wrong idea. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  if (OBJ_TAINTED(src))
      ^
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/fl_type.h:151:25: note: expanded from macro 'OBJ_TAINTED'
#define OBJ_TAINTED     RB_OBJ_TAINTED     /**< @old{RB_OBJ_TAINTED} */
                        ^
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/fl_type.h:118:30: note: expanded from macro 'RB_OBJ_TAINTED'
#define RB_OBJ_TAINTED       RB_OBJ_TAINTED
                             ^
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/fl_type.h:812:1: note: 'RB_OBJ_TAINTED' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
RBIMPL_ATTR_DEPRECATED(("taintedness turned out to be a wrong idea."))
^
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/attr/deprecated.h:36:53: note: expanded from macro 'RBIMPL_ATTR_DEPRECATED'
# define RBIMPL_ATTR_DEPRECATED(msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__ msg))
                                                    ^
unicode.c:38:5: warning: 'RB_OBJ_TAINT' is deprecated: taintedness turned out to be a wrong idea. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    OBJ_TAINT(obj);
    ^
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/fl_type.h:149:25: note: expanded from macro 'OBJ_TAINT'
#define OBJ_TAINT       RB_OBJ_TAINT       /**< @old{RB_OBJ_TAINT} */
                        ^
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/fl_type.h:116:30: note: expanded from macro 'RB_OBJ_TAINT'
#define RB_OBJ_TAINT         RB_OBJ_TAINT
                             ^
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/fl_type.h:843:1: note: 'RB_OBJ_TAINT' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
RBIMPL_ATTR_DEPRECATED(("taintedness turned out to be a wrong idea."))
^
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/attr/deprecated.h:36:53: note: expanded from macro 'RBIMPL_ATTR_DEPRECATED'
# define RBIMPL_ATTR_DEPRECATED(msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__ msg))
                                                    ^
unicode.c:1039:20: error: incompatible function pointer types passing 'VALUE (get_categories_param *)' (aka 'unsigned long (struct _get_categories_param *)') to parameter of type 'VALUE (*)(VALUE)' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(unsigned long)') [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
  return rb_ensure(get_categories_internal, (VALUE)&param,
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/iterator.h:425:25: note: passing argument to parameter 'b_proc' here
VALUE rb_ensure(VALUE (*b_proc)(VALUE), VALUE data1, VALUE (*e_proc)(VALUE), VALUE data2);
                        ^
unicode.c:1040:20: error: incompatible function pointer types passing 'VALUE (WString *)' (aka 'unsigned long (struct _WString *)') to parameter of type 'VALUE (*)(VALUE)' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(unsigned long)') [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
                   get_categories_ensure, (VALUE)&wstr);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/iterator.h:425:62: note: passing argument to parameter 'e_proc' here
VALUE rb_ensure(VALUE (*b_proc)(VALUE), VALUE data1, VALUE (*e_proc)(VALUE), VALUE data2);
                                                             ^
unicode.c:1057:20: error: incompatible function pointer types passing 'VALUE (get_categories_param *)' (aka 'unsigned long (struct _get_categories_param *)') to parameter of type 'VALUE (*)(VALUE)' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(unsigned long)') [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
  return rb_ensure(get_categories_internal, (VALUE)&param,
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/iterator.h:425:25: note: passing argument to parameter 'b_proc' here
VALUE rb_ensure(VALUE (*b_proc)(VALUE), VALUE data1, VALUE (*e_proc)(VALUE), VALUE data2);
                        ^
unicode.c:1058:20: error: incompatible function pointer types passing 'VALUE (WString *)' (aka 'unsigned long (struct _WString *)') to parameter of type 'VALUE (*)(VALUE)' (aka 'unsigned long (*)(unsigned long)') [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
                   get_categories_ensure, (VALUE)&wstr);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.
.
.
2 warnings and 6 errors generated.
make: *** [unicode.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-23/3.2.0/unicode-0.4.4.4/gem_make.out

  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:102:in `run'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:51:in `block in make'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in `each'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in `make'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:42:in `build'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:170:in `build_extension'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:204:in `block in build_extensions'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:201:in `each'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:201:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:843:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.5.6/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:76:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.5.6/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.5.6/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:205:in `install'
  /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-.
.
.
An error occurred while installing unicode (0.4.4.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

I would really appreciate any help that you can provide.
Thanks.

- I tried "xcode-select --install" to check if there was something missing
- I've tried with asdf version manager to check if the issue was related to rbenv

Comment: In the project folder, with correct Ruby enabled by rbenv, can you try this command? `gem install unicode -- -Wno-incompatible-function-pointer-types`

Comment: I get this error when I try this command:

ERROR:  Error installing unicode:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/john.doe.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.4/ext/unicode
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/bin/ruby -I /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0 extconf.rb --with-cflags\=-Wno-incompatible-function-pointer-types
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure where that `ruby.h` path comes from, in my system is is `/Users/mike/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby.h` and should be the same for you

Comment: Can you try giving us output of 
`ruby -rrbconfig -e 'puts RbConfig::CONFIG["rubyhdrdir"]'`? You can also try running `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` but if you use XCode it can mess something up that I'm not familiar with

Comment: ideas lifted from here, but don't just copy paste everything into your terminal ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559255/error-while-installing-json-gem-mkmf-rb-cant-find-header-files-for-ruby

Comment: Thanks for your help @MikeSzyndel, I reinstalled ruby and running gem install unicode -- -Wno-incompatible-function-pointer-types solved the issue

Comment: I’m glad it worked, but still wonder what was the actual issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

gem install unicode -- --with-cflags="-Wno-incompatible-function-pointer-types"

Comment: I get this error when I try this command:

ERROR:  Error installing unicode:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/john.doe.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.4/ext/unicode
/Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/bin/ruby -I /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0 extconf.rb --with-cflags\=-Wno-incompatible-function-pointer-types
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /Users/john.doe/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

Comment: I reinstalled Ruby and ran this command again. The issue got solved. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a good idea to add it to your bundler config file, when using bundler:  bundle config build.unicode --with-cflags="-Wno-incompatible-function-pointer-types"

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this same issue today after installing the newest Sonoma 14.4 (M1 Chip).

I was able to to resolve this with the suggested:

```
gem install unicode -- --with-cflags="-Wno-incompatible-function-pointer-types"
```

Then I could finish out the bundler with

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score -2):

Check if this helps. Similar issue is pointed out here

https://github.com/blackwinter/unicode/issues/4

Comment: This link is absolutely unrelated to the question

Answer (score -2):

You may find this useful: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/19403

In my case, I just decided to use ruby 3.2.3

Comment: What does this link has to do with the question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: related to: ` Failed to build gem native extension.` error
The posted link above is from this thread: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/2123 -

Comment: Gems can fail to build for a number of reasons. It's absolutely unrelated. Please read the error message carefully before posting wrong answers.